Which episode of The Hitchhiker?
When I was about 8 or 9 I was flicking through TV channels. A TV show came on where a guy hitched a lift at night in a truck driven by a woman.
She started telling him a story about a man who jumped from the top if the Empire State Building. She said that when he was found his face was all messed up like this...
At that point she turned to face the guy and her face went all weird. Using sfx her eyes popped out and tongue and mouth went all weird.
Anyway, that's all I remember as I covered my eyes and sprinted out of the room.
I've been searching for it ever since and just saw The Hitchhiker on IMDB and it sounds like it is this program.
Does anyone know which episode it was that I was watching (if indeed it was The Hitchhiker).

It was not The Hitchhiker, but Pee-Wee's Big Adventure, and the woman truck-driver was Large Marge.  Here's the clip.

Oh my god! This has haunted me for 22 years! Lol! That is the clip! Thanks so much! Scared me to death when I was 8 lol!
